Spring controller and processing of parameter string as an array of strings
I encountered this problem. I have a simple spring REST controller that has a get method, it should process a request like this http://localhost:8080/test/get?params=["param1", "param2", "param3"]
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value="/get")
    public List<String> test(@RequestParam List<String> stringList) {
        return stringList;
    }
}

As a result, in my application I have in the stringList = ["["param1"", ""param2"", ""param3"]"]
I understand that if I fix the request itself to http://localhost:8080/test/get?params=param1, param2, param3 then I will get stringList = ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
How do I need to redesign my controller to achieve the same result without changing the query itself and without manually deleting extra characters?
I didn't find similar examples on the Internet, so I decided to ask my question here, at least direct me to where I can read about it

Spring controller won't parse your parameters for unknown design pattern. You should do it yourself. You cannot find examples out there because you have used a pattern that isn't recognized as a parameter in Spring. For further reading you need to  make a step back to learn basics of parameter passing to spring controller in spring mvc.

Iterable request params should be sent like this: http://localhost:8080/test/get?params=param1&params=param2&params=param3. Otherwise you can treat it as a String and convert to a valid collection using ObjectMapper or your own parser. POST with appropriate request body is an option as well
